# Best type of B2B Reputation System?

Tags: feedback, web, b2b

The aim of recommender system for B2B platform is generating trust (against fraud).

Imagine you are a business man; you visit a website where many other users offers products for your business (for example, truck or packaging). How could the system help you to choose from many variants?

One way is FeedBack from users who already interacted with seller. But while FeedBack is good for a C2C (Customer-to-Customer, like ebay) website, it may not be so good for B2B.

(Amazon's recommendation system relies on users FeedBack -- but it's not B2B platform.)

Comment: The answer would be subjective. What is the aim of the recommender system (what is it recommending), how is feedback inputted, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing B2B reputation system to C2C/B2C's reputation systems is like comparing partner's for marriage vs date/one-night-stand.

People who dwell in business should know that B2B reputation relies on many factors that could not be easily built overnight. Seasoned purchasers or corporate users will look for various tell tale signs in addition to word of mouth and their experience to asses B2B business reputation and trustworthiness.

In addition, B users normally assessing their potential partners reputation by ordering small quantities of items or projects to minimize potential loss against fraud.

Also there is another issue of ensuring the reputation system itself is trustworthy in the first place (e.g. not rigged or manipulated by spam). Eventually, like all numbers, rating systems are easy to be manipulated - though I am sure this issue could be minimized given enough time and efforts.

So instead of trying to come out with a perfect reputation system, why do not change the angle: **make it easier for B users themselves to asses the reputation of the said business**.

- user feedbacks like what Aliexpress/Alibaba have is a bare minimum.
- show some parameters that indicate business trustworthiness in one
  place for easy assesment (e.g. what is the BBB rating, what is the
  company registration, location, SSL certificates, modes of payment, accept escrow, etc)

Hopefully after several iterations you could find out which kind of indicators are more important to asses business reputation and translates it into some kind of KPI as suggested by @Alexey

Here is some example of how Alibaba deals with reputation issues normally associated with China's supplier http://masoo.en.alibaba.com/company_profile.html I am pretty sure no scoring system could match this kind of information.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop some metrics, which have values for your customers. Then you could use it either separately or integrate into one or several indexes which are used to increase trust for companies.

Metrics development is based on information concerning companies. The source for such data is your site. Play some cases.

- *Contract*. You are going to contract. Is there enough information concerning partner? Which additional information could be convincing for making deal with him (payment method, goods or services details, ...)?
- *Support*. You have some question. How can you communicate to parter to solve it?
- *Trouble*. Are there any means to solve it quickly?
- *Process*. Analyse contracting processes between users on your site. How fast responds partner and other data you can collect tracing the processes.

All this collected data could be transformed to some metrics.
[image]

Comment: Sounds good. Are there any scientific works about it (specially B2B)?

Comment: I think [Key Performance Indicators](http://www.klipfolio.com/resources/kpi-examples) would be useful, they have scientific background. I've added a picture in the post.

Comment: Did u suppose to gain information about such Indicators by FeedBack?

Comment: Feedback is one of sources, but it's subjective and not reliable. Pay attention to the data which you can get from processes on your site. I think the tools which are on your site for B2B interaction could provide some info.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a B2B ecommerce platform, you could rely on past purchases. 
The assumption is that a customer buying a lot of products in category A is obviously capable of selling those products to end customers. That indicates that the customer knows about products of category A.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend studying the Amazon system.  Many businesses operate buying discounted products on Amazon and reselling them.  There are tried and true approaches to credibility reporting including Dun and Bradstreet and BBB.  Apparently you may be mining for the next big thing in B2B or C2C business credibility reporting.  I suggest investing in your idea and studying models that are truly effective in providing relevant information on business credibility.  You may be on to something about the American Capitalist system, whereby businesses operate with very little credibility reporting

Comment: You've not really provided an answer to to question about what is a good B2) reputation system. You say 'study the amazon system' but that isn't an answer; you need to explain how it's relevant. If there is an answer in here then you're forcing people to go off and start googling the references you've made (Dun and Bradstreet and BBB) whereas if these are relevant to the question then you should explain them here in your answer.